# JavaFX interaction in stackpane with multiple controllers

Tags: javafx

my Layout is:
[MVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxkGa.png)

I have trouble interacting with the controllers of other classes (yes, I know there are several threads about this - but I still don't get what's wrong ).

So, basically I have a StackPane "root" which includes two AnchorPane's: "vertMenu" and "content". "root" The StackPane is nested in a VBox for Layout purposes. "vertMenu" will contain different buttons to load content (from fxml-files) to the content pane - not implemented in this MVE.

I want to press "menuButton" in class RootController to disable "vertMenu" from VertMenuController Class to initeract with the UI on the content pane which comes from ContentController class.

My Code:

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            this.stage = primaryStage;
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Root.fxml"));
            Parent myPane = loader.load();
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(myPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Root Controller Class:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RootController {
    @FXML private StackPane root;
    @FXML private Button menuButton;
    @FXML private Button bb;
    VertMenuController vertMenuC;
    ContentController contentC;

    @FXML private void initialize() {

    }
    
    @FXML private void menuButtonAction() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VertMenuView.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        vertMenuC = loader.getController();
        
        vertMenuC.disableMenu();
        
    }
    

}
```

Root View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<VBox prefHeight="450.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.RootController">
   <children>
      <StackPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(222,222,222);">
         <children>
            <fx:include source="ContentView.fxml" />
            <fx:include source="VertMenuView.fxml" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <Button fx:id="menuButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#menuButtonAction" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="157.0" text="Button" />
      <Button fx:id="bb" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="154.0" text="Button" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

VertMenuController Class

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class VertMenuController {
    @FXML private AnchorPane vertMenu;
    @FXML private Button b1;
    @FXML private Button b2;
    @FXML private VBox vbo;
    
    
    public void disableMenu() {
        vertMenu.setDisable(true);
    }
    public void enableMenu() {
        vertMenu.setDisable(false);
    }
    
    public AnchorPane getVertMenu() {
        return vertMenu;
    }
    public VBox getBox() {
        return vbo;
    }
    
    
}
```

VertMenuView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="vertMenu" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="150.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.VertMenuController">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="vbo" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="150.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="b1" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="148.0" text="B1" />
            <Button fx:id="b2" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="148.0" text="B2" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

ContentController Class

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class ContentController {
    @FXML private AnchorPane content;
    @FXML private Button b3;
    @FXML private Label ausgabe;
    
    
    
    @FXML private void b3Action() {
        ausgabe.setText("b2 pressed");
    }
    
    public void setAusgabe() {
        this.ausgabe.setText("Hello World");
    }
    
    
}
```

ContentView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="content" maxWidth="600.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ContentController">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="b3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#b3Action" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Button" />
            <Label fx:id="ausgabe" prefHeight="113.0" prefWidth="610.0" text="Label" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I do not get any exceptions, so I think I do correctly make a reference to the "verticalMenuController" in the root controller class. But unfortunately I can't disable the AnchorPane "vertMenu".

Thank you very much so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the FXML file with

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VertMenuView.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
vertMenuC = loader.getController();

vertMenuC.disableMenu();
```

the `FXMLLoader` creates a new instance of the UI defined in `VertMenuView.fxml` and a new controller instance which is associated to that UI. You assign the root of the UI to the local variable `root`. When you call `vertMenuC.disableMenu`, you disable the menu in the new instance of the UI that was created by the `FXMLLoader`. However, that UI is a different instance to the one that was loaded and displayed by the `<fx:include>`, so you don't see any effect.

Instead, you need a reference to the controller that is associated with the UI that is loaded by the `<fx:include>` element. You can do this by [injecting the "Nested Controller"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) into the main controller.

First, add a `fx:id` to your `fx:include`:

```xml
<fx:include fx:id="vertMenu" source="VertMenuView.fxml" />
```

And then inject this into your `RootController`. The rule is that the field name for the controller is the `fx:id` with the text `"Controller"` appended:

```
public class RootController {
    @FXML private StackPane root;
    @FXML private Button menuButton;
    @FXML private Button bb;
    @FXML private VertMenuController vertMenuController;

    @FXML private void initialize() {

    }

    // ...

}
```

Now you can just call `disableMenu` directly on the injected controller:

```
@FXML private void menuButtonAction() {

    vertMenuController.disableMenu();

}
```

You probably need to do the same with your `ContentController` too.

Comment: Aah makes sense. I had not in mind that this will of course create a new instance of the UI... Thank you!